# Why my realtime databaase cannot be worked?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have faced the problem that my firebase cannot be worked as well and it just shows me nothing ( white page ) in my application. I need to use firebase to show the material in the recycler view. However, as the new user for firebase, I set my recycler view in string form and after it, I also want to use as one is image one is text. But I think that I need to fix the first problem as well. Can somebody help me? Thank you for your help!!

My original code :

```html
package com.example.assignment_mad

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.example.assignment_mad.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.assignment_mad.databinding.FragmentNotificationBinding
import com.example.assignment_mad.databinding.FragmentSearchPageBinding
import com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_notification_.*


class Notification_Fragment : Fragment( ) {

    val database=Firebase.database
    val myRef=database.getReference("message")

    private var _binding:FragmentNotificationBinding?=null
    private val binding get()=_binding!!

    private lateinit var dbref: DatabaseReference

    private lateinit var newRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var newArrayList: ArrayList<Company>
    private lateinit var tempArrayList: ArrayList<Company>
    lateinit var imageId:Array<Int>
    lateinit var heading:Array<String>
    lateinit var news:Array<String>

    private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
    private var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.MyViewHolder>? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        var views =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification_, container, false)
        newRecyclerView=views.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return views



    }

    override fun onViewCreated(itemView: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onViewCreated(itemView, savedInstanceState)

        newArrayList= arrayListOf<Company>()
        tempArrayList= arrayListOf<Company>()
        getUserdata()

    }

    private fun getUserdata() {
        dbref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notification")
        dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for (companySnapshot in snapshot.children){
                        val company=companySnapshot.getValue(Company::class.java)
                        newArrayList.add(company!!)
                    }

                    newRecyclerView.adapter=NotificationAdapter(newArrayList)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
            }

        })
        
        newRecyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        newRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        newRecyclerView.adapter=adapter
    }


}
```

The adapter code :

```html
package com.example.assignment_mad

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.dropdown_item.view.*


class NotificationAdapter(private val companysList:ArrayList<Company>):RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {



    private var mListener:onItemClickListener?=null

    interface onItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: onItemClickListener){
        mListener=listener
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        val itemView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView,mListener)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem=companysList[position]
        holder.titleImage.text=currentItem.titleImage
//        holder.titleImage.setImageResource(currentItem.titleImage)
        holder.tvHeading.text=currentItem.heading
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return companysList.size
    }

    //to insert the post detail


    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View,listener: onItemClickListener?):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val titleImage:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_image)
//        val titleImage:ShapeableImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_image)
        val tvHeading: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeading)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                listener?.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Data :

```html
package com.example.assignment_mad

data class Company(var titleImage:String?=null,var heading:String?=null)

//data class Company(var titleImage:Int,var heading:String)
```

The xml file ( as you see, actually i need image and text together )  :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

<!--    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView-->
<!--        android:layout_width="80dp"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="80dp"-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/title_image"-->
<!--        android:scaleType="centerCrop"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"-->
<!--        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCorner"-->
<!--        android:src="@drawable/company_logo_1"/>    -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Self Brief"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Candidate Biden Called Saudi Arable a Pareft eaft."
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/title_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_image"
        android:background="@color/underline"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

These is the problem faced. Or some one else can directly teach me how to set image for realtime database?

My database pic :

[image]

Comment: I do not understand very well the question, the problem is that you can't save the url where the image is saved? or you can not load the url in the shapeable image view? :D

Comment: @MACROSystems basically i want to design like this page can load the information from the firebase which are one is image one is text. But for testing, i code these two is text view to prove these codes can be functioned or not but it still show white screen for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RecyclerView` is showing no item because you are never initializing the `adapter` variable, which you are setting to your RecyclerView's adapter. Initialize `adapter` variable inside `onViewCreated()`

```
override fun onViewCreated(itemView: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(itemView, savedInstanceState)
    newArrayList= arrayListOf<Company>()
    tempArrayList= arrayListOf<Company>()

    adapter = NotificationAdapter(newArrayList) //Initialize adapter

    getUserdata()
}
```

Inside `onDataChange()`, after adding data to `newArrayList`, notify adapter by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on `adapter`. It would update the RecyclerView.

```
private fun getUserdata() {
        dbref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notification")
        dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for (companySnapshot in snapshot.children){
                        val company=companySnapshot.getValue(Company::class.java)
                        newArrayList.add(company!!)
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
            }

        })
        
        newRecyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        newRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        newRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But after i follow your code, it show me `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property newArrayList has not been initialized         at com.example.assignment_mad.Notification_Fragment.onViewCreated(Notification_Fragment.kt:66)` and let my application stopping so I add `newArrayList= arrayListOf<Company>()` in onCreateView but also show me white screen only. And for the line `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` the system requires add ?. and I add it. Is this possible make my firebase cannot show?

Comment: You should debug and check if you are getting data from firebase or not.